# A number field from the series for $e$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$E =  \left\{\, \sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{d(n)}{n!}  \Biggm| d\colon\mathbb{N}→\{0,1\}\,\right\}.$$

I believe $E$ is of measure $0$ and need a proof.

Comment: what's d(n)? ????

Comment: @user140943 It's the image of a natural number $n\geq0$ defined by the map $d:\mathbb{N}\to[0,1]$.

Comment: oh so it's an arbitrary function

Comment: Where's the number field hidden in this question?

Comment: Well you can put the numbers in a correspondence with all sequences of the form (0 or 1, 0 or 1, 0 or 1,...) which is an uncountable set (it corresponds to all numbers between 0 and 1 written in binary "decimal").

Comment: @user140943 : Did you have some particular one-to-one correspondence in mind?  And how do you propose to make use of the fact that this set is uncountable?

Comment: The original question had $d\colon\mathbb N\to\{0,1\}$ instead of $d\colon\mathbb N\to[0,1]$, which makes a *huge* difference (with the interval, clearly $[0,1]\subseteq E$).

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Please do not *change* questions. (e.g. I ended up writing a full answer to the wrong question because you changed $\{0,1\}$ to $[0,1]$.)

Comment: Wait so which is it? The interval or just the two numbers?

Comment: I (Warwick Zeamer) posed this same problem in the American mathematical monthly back in the mid eighties. It was solved by Micheal Pelling and his answer was essentially what has been presented above.

Comment: What my question proposed was that the field generated by these series was a proper uncountable subfield of the reals holding many transcendental numbers because of its uncountability.  Pelling proved that the field was indeed a proper subfield of the reals because closing under the field operations does not take you out of measure zero. As this field stands properly between Q and R it would be interesting to see what algebraic numbers are contained in it and whether its subfield of algebraic numbers is a normal extension of Q.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $N>1$
$$0\le \sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac{d(n)}{n!}\le \frac1{N!}\sum_{k=0}^\infty N^{-k}= \frac1{(N-1)!(N-1)}$$
Hence $E$ can be covered by as little as $2^N$ intervals of lenth $\frac1{(N-1)!(N-1)}$.